# Placing my real estate ads on a google map in my website

Tags: google-maps

Is there any way to place a map on my website and put there markers with the number of real estate ads (my ads) in some areas and when zoom in to that zone to expand that marker to more markers (one for each ad) using google maps api?

Comment: Markers clustering would be the choice which is available in Google maps V3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done based on your number of markers and at what zoom level you want to scatter the all other markers.

Go through the below link for details

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers